# Why do "display: inline-block" elements become 100% width when text is wrapping?

Tags: css

I've got a portfolio-like page, displaying images in a grid with a title on top of it. The title is set to *inline-block* and has a background color, width depends on the length on the title.
Whenever a title becomes too long to fit within the parent article it wraps to a second row; no problem. 
But why does the auto width result in 100% now?

```
.content{
  background: pink;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.title{

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;  
  text-align: center;
}
h2{
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);

}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6qtw7duf/

Comment: What browser or device are you seeing this behavior in? The fiddle you provided renders each of the three example texts at 33% width using the latest Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Xorandnotor it is 100% of the 33%

Comment: i can see 33% for each container...

Comment: Because of `line-boxes`.

Comment: @Neal - I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic or not here.  Yes, it's 100% of the 33%, which is the defined width of the inline-block element.  This is the anticipated behavior.

Comment: @Xorandnotor Yea... hence I downvoted here.... That is standard behavior, I am not sure what the question is for.

Answer (score 2):

Ok..let's explain this in simple term
[image]

Comment: Indeed, it does inherit from the parents parent. But why does the third column have this behavior, and the first two don't?
To be more specific: I would assume the multi-line H2's width to become as large as its largest line of text, just at the single-line H2's render.

The single-line H2's aren't 100% width of the parent because of inline-block. 

Editted the fiddle with borders to be more clear and make the H2 container's width 100%; Which make the H2's nicely centered and as big as their content. EXPECT for the multiline H2's which become 100% of parent?

Comment: inline-block elements will wrap if their contents overflow their parent container..that is of course if you don't specify a css rule that can override this default behaviour....for example the css rule "overflow:visible;width:...."  will trigger an overriding of this default html spec behaviour..every language has standards we question..so in a nutshell we accept it...

Comment: Of course we have to accept. Just trying to understand the behavior. 

..... actually the example now seems to work as I expected. ?!?! :) 
Does resolve as I intended after all.
Thanks for thinking with me here.